# Aerogear - how to send a push notification from one device to another device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, aerogear

I have tried Aerogear push notification and able to send a push message from aerogear web portal to my iOS device.

But right now i am looking for sending a push message from 1 iOS device to another iOS device with the help of Aerogear.

Is this possible and how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this directly device to device.  Seems like some else would be a better fit than push for this(just opinion without knowing your use case :))